# second part of a javascript function not running?

Tags: javascript

```
function blocksLogic(){

if(gameRunning == 0){
    var blocks = new Array(7);
    for(var i=0; i <7; i++){
        blocks[i] = new Array(7);
    }
    for(var x=0; x < 7; x++){
        for(var y=0; y < 7; y++){
            blocks[x][y] = false;
            console.log(blocks[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
console.log("gamerunning function ran");
// COLLISION!!!!!!!
for(var brickX = 0; x < 7; x++){
    console.log("for x has been run!");
    for( var brickY = 0; y < 7; y++){
            console.log("for y has been run!");
            var tempBrickX = brickX * 105 + 34;
            var tempBrickY = brickY * 25 - 10;
            //top collision
        if(ballY >= tempBrickX && ballX >= tempBrickX && ballX <= tempBrickX + BRICK_WIDTH){
            console.log("The top of this block has been hit!");
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        }
            //bottom collision
        if(ballY <= tempBrickY + BRICK_HEIGHT && ballX >= tempBrickX  && ballX >= tempBrickX){
            console.log("The bottom of this brick has been hit!");
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        }       
    }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/t2Zq79BG

The function blocksLogic is not running the code below the comment "//COLLISION!"
its probably something really simple but im just starting to get into coding with javascript(thats why my code formatting sucks)
i added alot of debugging console.logs to see what was running and what wasnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(var brickX = 0; x < 7; x++)`

x is undefined here, that's why the loop never runs (this looks like a copy paste error from above). Make sure to use brickX instead:

`for(var brickX = 0; brickX < 7; brickX++)`

Answer (score 1):

Check your variables inside for loops. Why do you declare brickX, but then check x? Change to

```
for(var x = 0; x < 7; x++){
console.log("for x has been run!");
for( var y = 0; y < 7; y++){
        console.log("for y has been run!");
        var tempBrickX = x * 105 + 34;
        var tempBrickY = y * 25 - 10;
        //top collision
    if(ballY >= tempBrickX && ballX >= tempBrickX && ballX <= tempBrickX + BRICK_WIDTH){
        console.log("The top of this block has been hit!");
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }
        //bottom collision
    if(ballY <= tempBrickY + BRICK_HEIGHT && ballX >= tempBrickX  && ballX >= tempBrickX){
        console.log("The bottom of this brick has been hit!");
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }       
}
```

}